# gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify' Command failed:

Tags: cmd, gulp, gulp-notify

I'm trying to set up a basic workflow with Gulp and I'm getting the following error whenever I call gulp-notify.

```
Design5-Joel:Sura-child design5$ gulp notify
[14:00:17] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Websites/atoll-wp/wp-content/themes/Sura-child/gulpfile.js
[14:00:17] Starting 'notify'...
[14:00:17] Finished 'notify' after 10 ms
[14:00:17] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Hello Gulp!
[14:00:47] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
Message:
    Command failed: /Users/design5/Documents/Websites/atoll-wp/wp-content/themes/Sura-child/node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -title "Gulp notification" -message "Hello Gulp!" -appIcon "/Users/design5/Documents/Websites/atoll-wp/wp-content/themes/Sura-child/node_modules/gulp-notify/assets/gulp.png" -json "true"

Details:
    killed: true
    code: null
    signal: SIGTERM
    cmd: /Users/design5/Documents/Websites/atoll-wp/wp-content/themes/Sura-child/node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -title "Gulp notification" -message "Hello Gulp!" -appIcon "/Users/design5/Documents/Websites/atoll-wp/wp-content/themes/Sura-child/node_modules/gulp-notify/assets/gulp.png" -json "true"
```

The strange thing is that everything in the function fires, including the notification, and then exactly 30 seconds later the error comes up. This is particularly a problem if I want to watch a folder.

If anyone else has found a solution to this it would be much appreciated

edit: gulp-notify isn't a mandatory aspect of the function, so the easy solution would be to just disable notify but I'd like to be able to solve this in case I run into similar issues in the future.

I've tried;

- updating all dependencies
- verifying node's cache
- reinstalling all packages
- running package.json and gulpfile.js through validators.